# Setting UIBarButtonItem to image with no background

Tags: objective-c

Currently I'm setting my UIBarButtonItem to a 40x40 px image with a transparent background. When I go to set the UIBarButtonItem to this image, it produces the result below:

[image]

I just want the image of the guy without the green background. How should I go about doing this?

**Code I've Tried:**

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile-barbutton.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.navigationController action:@selector(myselector)];
```

Also tried the following (as well as initializing the bar with initWithTitle:@"" ...

**Worked But Selector No Longer References UINavigationController**

The following code produces the exception [MasterViewController toggleMenu]: unrecognized selector because the selector is inside my NavigationController class, which was previously referenced with the UIBarButtonItem but isn't any longer.

```
      UIButton *profileBarButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
    [profileBarButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile-barbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [profileBarButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:profileBarButton];

    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTarget:self.navigationController];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(toggleMenu)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the background image, not the image. Try this:

```
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile-barbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: see my edited question. I don't think your above solution works.

Comment: Can you try initializing the button without the image? UIBarButtonItems are NOT subclasses of UIView and may act differently, so you could try using the "initWithCustomView" and pass in a regular UIButton with a custom background image.

Comment: that works, but my selector no longer works. Would you mind taking a look please? Thanks

Comment: You should set the selector on your `UIButton` only, and set no selector on your `UIBarButtonItem`.